# Svelte unload content

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is it possible to unload an image? E.g. if you download a lot of images with an infinity scroll something like lazy loading in both directions.

And if the event `visibilitychange` is used by svelte to unload everything that isn't displayed or do I need to do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a general web dev question. Svelte does nothing by itself when visibility changes.

You can load elements manually, but it's usually a bit more complex than just adding or removing elements when visible/invisible. Keeping scroll position, pop in, etc.

I replace elements with empty divs with specific height and keep 1000px from first visible and load 1000px from last visible element.

Comment: but the images are still in memory or are they written to the hard drive?

Comment: If you remove it from the dom the browser will clean it up from memory during gc. As images are being downloaded they are written to cache, next time they are requested they get loaded from cache (probably, if `Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache` is sent, then they are not written to cache).